# What is the best Linux filesystem for MySQL (InnoDB)?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, filesystems, benchmarking

I tried to look for benchmark on the performances of various filesystems with MySQL InnoDB but couldn't find any.

My database workload is the typical web-based OLTP, about 90% read, 10% write. Random IO.

Among popular filesystems such as ext3, ext4, xfs, jfs, Reiserfs, Reiser4, etc. which one do you think is the best for MySQL?

Comment: s/he had better response at http://serverfault.com/questions/29193/what-is-the-best-linux-filesystem-for-mysql-innodb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at [Lessons Learned in Building a Highly Scalable MySQL Database](http://www.mysqlconf.com/mysql2008/public/schedule/detail/625).
They benchmarked mysql with some of these filesystems and jfs looks like a clear the winner.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with [InnoDB](http://www.innodb.com/products/innodb/info/) this [two part interaction at the mysqlperformanceblog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/26/heikki-tuuri-innodb-answers-part-i/) with [Heikki Tuuri](http://www.mysqlconf.com/mysql2008/public/schedule/speaker/1311) who created it should good reading.